# In Illustrator, how to replicate exactly the displayed CMYK mode colors in RGB mode?

Tags: color, cmyk, color-conversion, rgb, color-reproduction

I have a two stop gradient in CMYK color mode (FOGRA). After converting the document to RGB mode (sRGB), there's a slight color shift between the two gradients. The RGB gradient is a bit redder/darker. Since the CMYK mode gradient was displayed on the screen, shouldn't I be able to exactly replicate its colors in RGB mode? How do I exactly replicate the CMYK gradient in sRGB mode?

CMYK gradient
[image]

RGB gradient
[image]

Comment: There's not much you can really do here. The CMYK colours you see on-screen are basically a simulation in RGB of what you will get when something is printed. A computer can't display real CMYK colour. RGB and CMYK images are fundamentally different colour systems. The two can never be exactly the same

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy with how the CMYK gradient is printing. Maybe I should've phrased my question more as, how do I exactly replicate the RGB-simulated CMYK gradient sidplayed on the screen after I go to settings and convert the document from CMYK to sRGB mode? After I convert, they are not exactly the same on screen.

Comment: I suppose you could add more stops to the gradient by using the eyedropper in the gradient panel to sample the colours [see example](https://imgur.com/RdXTG02)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

No, see there is a critical thing that you are overlooking. The things a vector drawing engine can do is limitted by the standard formats the application targets.

So essentially by converting to RGB leads to the gradient being interpolated in RGB. Which is different from the CMYK interpolation.

If it was just pixels then yes no problem.

Answer (score 1):

A CMYK gradient on the screen does not exist. It is a simulation generated by the internal algorithms of the software used.

One way to exactly match is to actually use the CMYK simulation as the RGB values. You can use a screen color picker to see what are the displayed RGB values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.